# What kind of service is runit's svlogd expecting?

Tags: logging, runit

The runit manual states that in the configuration one  can use an option to submit logs to:

> ua.b.c.d[:port]
>       tells svlogd to transmit the first len characters of selected log messages to the IP address a.b.c.d, port number port. If port isn’t
>   set, the default port for syslog is used (514). len can be set through
>   the -l option, see below. If svlogd has trouble sending udp packets,
>   it writes error messages to the log directory. Attention: logging
>   through udp is unreliable, and should be used in private networks
>   only.

I know that `rsyslogd` is running list on this port. 
So this could be one possible option...
But are there any other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is slightly vague, but from the sound of it, I think you are asking if you can use `svlogd` to send syslog messages to another program besides `rsyslogd`.  The answer is, **any program that provided a syslog service would suffice.**  There is more than just `rsyslogd` that provides a syslog network service.

However, the way runit was intended to "natively" handle logging is probably backwards from what you are thinking.

The idea is that you have a service of some kind, and that service writes output through stdout or stderr.  The `runsv` program will bring up `svlogd` and erect a pipe between your service and `svlogd`; all your service has to do is send data to stdout/stderr, svlogd will write directly to disk, and life is good.  Because the pipe is maintained by `runsv`, should there be issues with the service going down, output is still captured and delivered to `svlogd` - so in *theory*, you don't loose logging data due to a service crash.

There is another program by the same author, [`socklog`](http://smarden.org/socklog/), that acts as a syslog front-end that funnels to a `svlogd`.  Because there are a lot of programs that just assume that `/dev/log` is available, `socklog` provides this interface so that syslog data can be captured - it acts as a substitute syslog service.  *This is the opposite of what you are suggesting.*

I'm not saying you shouldn't use syslog, I'm just saying that there's more than one way to do this.  If you really want to shunt your output from svlogd back to syslog, then yes, any old syslog service will do just fine, but it may be worth considering going "all native" and ditching `rsyslogd` altogether, if your installation permits this.